# Ошибка при добавлении rc файлов Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator, qmake

Проект был без ошибок, пока не добавила иконку приложение qt

В .pro добавила

```
RC_FILE = app_icon.rc
```

В файле app_icon.rc

```
IDI_ICON1 ICON DISCARDABLE "edu.ico"
```

edu.ico находится в папке с самим проектом

Ошибка в QtCreator 5.12.3

> :-1: error: [Makefile.Release:72: release/app_icon_res.o] Error 1

Насколько могу судить, проблема не с проектом, а с добавлением rc-файла в .pro, ведь когда убираю эту строку — проект работает.

Есть ли другой способ добавления иконки в приложение для windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в поломанном файле **edu.ico**
Решение есть